# Database normalization and lazy development

Tags: php, mysql

I believe the question have emerged as my irritation of doing twice as much work as I could imagine is necessary.

I accept the idea that I could be lacking experience with both MySQL and PHP to think of a simpler solution.

My issue is that I have several tables (and I'd might be adding more) and of these is a parent table, only containing two fields - an id (int) and a name identifying it.

At this moment, I have seven tables with at least 15 fields in each one. Every table has a field, containing the id which I can link to the parent table.

All of these data isn't required to be filled - you will just have to create that one entry in the parent table. For the other tables, I have separate forms.

Now, these forms are made for updating the data in the fields, which means I have to pull out the data from the table if any data is available.

What I would like to do is when I receive the data from my form, I could just use an UPDATE query in my model. But if the table I want to update doesn't have an entry for that specific id, I need to do an insert.

So, my current pseudo code is like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT id FROM table_x WHERE parent_id = ".$parent_id;
$res = $mysql_query($sql);
if( mysql_num_rows($res) == 1 )
{
  $sql = "UPDATE table_x SET ... WHERE parent_id = ".$parent_id;
}
else
{
  $sql = "INSERT INTO table_x VALUES ( ... )";
}
mysql_query($sql);
```

I have two do this for every table I have - can I do something different or smarter or is this just the way it has to be done? Cause this seems very inefficient to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Syntax
```

It will insert if record not found,
otherwise, it will update existing record,
and you can skip the check before insert - [details](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

**This assuming relation for each 7 table to the parent table is 1:1**

Answer (score 2):

Or use [`REPLACE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html) instead of `INSERT` - it's an insert, but will do an DELETE and then INSERT when a unique key (such as the primary key) is violated.

Comment: I like the idea, which is why I gave your answer a vote - but ON DUPLICATE got me to the sulotion I needed.

Comment: `ON DUPLICATE` is the way to go, but only available since MySQL 4.1.0 - but you should be running a higher version by now :)

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql_query("UPDATE table table_x ..... WHERE parent_id=".$parent_id);
if (mysql_affected_rows()==0) {
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO .....");
}
```

Comment: please use code-formatting (i corrected that). also, i think the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`-solution is much more beautiful (and i'm sure it's faster).

Answer (score 0):

in mysql you can do this:

```
INSERT INTO table
  (
    col1,
    col2
  ) VALUES(
    'val1',
    'val2'
  ) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE table SET 
    col2 = 'val2'
```

take a look at the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) for more information